# Installation and deployment in Netbeans 8.2?

Tags: netbeans, ejb

my old computer was using `netbeans 7.2` it ran good.
but it was dumb when i rebuild it after repair my computer
I can't find where to download `7.2` version
it Doesn't run on netbeans 8.2
http://www.mediafire.com/download/c4l8vwl7523h1kl/eProjectRadioCabs-Group2-Bacth59B.rar

Answer (score 0):

On the Netbeans site, goto the Download page, one of the Links will be
"Archive", on that page is an drop down list to select version and build type.
Select your version and "Release" build type.

Or if everything goes well you just try this link:
https://netbeans.org/downloads/7.2/index.html